# More than one war file in Windows 2008 R2 tomcat 7

Tags: grails, tomcat7, windows-server-2008, war

In Mac, I can deploy 2+ war files to tomcat7 and it works.

But i have problem deploying 2 war files in Windows 2008 Tomcat7. One war file works but not 2 war files.

Error in server is

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I increased the memory by adding setenv.bat with

> set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx4048m
>   -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Comment: When are you running setenv.bat?  I don't use Windows any more, but when I did, I remember having problems setting environment variables without a reboot.  I resorted to using the Tomcat7w application ("Configure Tomcat") and setting the Java Options on the Java tab.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Windows Services doesn't work. 
It does not pick up increase memory. Startup.bat works just fine.

Answer was given to me (Alof)